# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "salir de cuentas"?

Tags: etimología, historia, expresiones

Cuando una mujer está embarazada se dice que "sale de cuentas" en una fecha determinada para referirse a la fecha en que se calcula que nacerá el bebé.

Me pregunto: ¿de dónde sale esta expresión? ¿Es solamente una reducción de algo así como "salir de las cuentas del nacimiento" o tiene un origen más rico?

La [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/cuenta) menciona:

> **salir de ~**, o **de ~s** una mujer.
>
> 1. locs. verbs. Haber cumplido el período de gestación sin dar a luz.

Comment: Hasta donde yo sé. Se trata de haber cumplido el periodo que, dada la supuesta fecundación, estimabas para el nacimiento de un hijo. Tengamos en cuenta que antiguamente las cuentas de la gestación se las hacía uno con muy pocos medios tecnológicos ni médicos. La expresión en sí de "hacerse las cuentas" indica en cierta manera una ligera inexactitud en los resultados.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El periodo de gestación humano es de nueve meses, pero eso no significa que sea un determinado número de días exacto.

Generalmente, el día exacto de la fecundación tampoco tiene por qué ser conocido.

Esto hace que sea muy difícil determinar el día exacto en que se producirá el alumbramiento, y tiempo atrás esto era aún más complicado.

Cuando alguien "salía de cuentas" era porque alcanzaba o había superado la fecha estimada para el alumbramiento por la matrona / médico que le atendía, lo que significaba que a partir de ese momento el parto debería ser inminente y podría producirse en cualquier momento.

Comment: Y las cuentas se hacían (y se siguen haciendo) a partir de la fecha de la última menstruación previa al embarazo.

Comment: Bueno, además, aunque se sepa la fecha de concepción, la biología siempre tiene algo de variabilidad.