# ¿Dónde se usa más «matrona» y dónde «partera»?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales

En una [respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/13422/9385) a otra pregunta, aprendí que en algunas regiones se usa *matrona* para la persona que apoya a la mujer cuando da a luz.  En México esta persona se llama *partera*.

¿Dónde se usa *partera*, *matrona*, o algún otro término?

Comment: En Argentina sólo se usa "partera", y tiene estudios para ejercer como tal, asistiendo al médico obstetra en el parto.

Comment: Algo más: usamos "matrona" sólo en sentido despectivo para referirnos a una mujer de aspecto maduro y, generalmente, de cierta corpulencia.

Comment: En España hasta donde yo sé se usa matrona y hace el seguimiento del embarazo además de ayudar en el parto

Comment: @blonfu - Te invito a agregar esta información a la respuesta wiki.

Answer (score 1):

Ambas apoyan en el parto, pero una tiene formación académica y la otra no.

Las enfermeras obstetras, matronas o comadronas tienen (o deberían tener) formación académica.

La partera no tiene una formación académica como tal, pero tiene experiencia asistiendo en partos.

> [**Matrón, na**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=Odao13n)
>   1. m. y f. Persona especialmente autorizada para asistir a las parturientas.
>
> [**Comadre**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=9sPYfty)
>   1. f. partera (‖ mujer que sin estudios asiste a la parturienta).

Answer (score 0):

- **Argentina**: sólo se usa "partera", y tiene estudios para ejercer como tal, asistiendo al médico obstetra en el parto.

Answer (score 0):

Según el DAMER, *matrona* se usa en Nicaragua y Puerto Rico:

> [**matrón, -na.**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=matrona)
>   **I.    1.**    m. y f. *Ni, PR.* Dueño o administrador de una casa de citas. prost.